# Restrict Lubuntu to suspend

Tags: suspend, lubuntu

Please help. If you know the solution for ubuntu, I'll try it.

I have Lenovo IdeaPad S10-3 (intel-atom netbook). After installing lubuntu 11.04 I realized that the system doesn't recover after suspend. It just hangs and I need to do hard reset.

Trying to implement various things didn't help so now I ask for a way to turn suspending OFF. To break is easier than to build =)

Or change suspend to hibernation. So that closing the notebook would not lead to hard reset to me. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu 11.04 uses gnome-power-manager. Therefore you can use gconf-editor to change various settings.

Try installing gconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

then run the editor

```
gconf-editor &
```

navigate to this part of the tree and change the suspend options to whichever action you want - use the values as described at the bottom hand right corner of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed a step further, running magic jack on virtualbox nt; where only wanted the monitor and harddrive to  slowdown.
composed a hack/script /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000_virtualbox-winnt
basically re-directing suspend/hibernation to ac powersaving state if the vm is running.

after reading many of the scripts and this informative post.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement

```
$ cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000_virtualbox-winnt 
#!/bin/sh

# Stollen from unattended-upgrades script
#  virtualbox winnt runs Magic Jack for phone service, attempting to keep this from 
#  hibernating or suspending durring the close of the lid.
#
# License:   GPL-2
#

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

if [[ ! `ps -ef | grep -q 'virtualbox.*winnt.*447f93e1-3603-4496-aaa0-38c4c56b7f38'` ]] ; then
        exit 0
fi

case "${1}" in
        suspend)
                pm-powersave ac
                exit 1
                ;;
        hibernate)
                pm-powersave ac
                exit 1
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
                # nothing
                ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Gnome , if you click the battery symbol you can change power settings. One of the possibilities is to define the action when closing the lid. I don't know if it is the same in lubuntu

Comment: unfortunately - it looks like lubuntu uses an older version of gnome-power-manager which doesnt have the same lid options as in natty.